# Does a linear cryptographic hash function exist?

Tags: hash, cryptography, hash-function, cryptographic-hash-function

Does a linear **cryptographic** hash function exist?

By linear I mean a function 'f' such that:

[image]

[image]

where + is mod n for some large constant n

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about crypto without involving programming.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That is not true, a function can be cryptographically strong as well as linear. One was even a condender for the SHA3 standard. See my answer.

Comment: @JohnMeacham You are probably right, this is just a question of me overlooking the `mod n` after quickly deciding it was off topic here. I'll delete my comment as it has too many upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,the cryptographically strong SWIFFT algorithm (a variant was a condender for the SHA3 standard) is linear such that h(a + b) = h(a) + h(b)

It is an interesting example of a hash that is both cryptographically strong and not psuedorandom. It is also another unexpected use of the much lauded FFT algorithm.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIFFT